# Create view with join conditions

Tags: mysql, join

I would like to create a view from 2 tables with some kind of conditional join (excuse my ignorance as I am new to SQL coding!).  The two tables are as follows:

**TABLE1**

```
Store | Product | MAC Price
S001 |  123 |    15.00
S001 |  456 |    17.50 
S002 |  123 |    16.00 
S002 |  456 |    17.50 
S002 |  789 |    20.00
```

**TABLE2:**

```
Store | Product | SELL Price
S001 |  123 |    25.00
S001 |  456 |    27.50 
S002 |  123 |    26.00 
SNAT |  123 |    35.00 
SNAT |  456 |    40.00
```

Where I am struggling with the syntax is that TABLE2 either has a price at the Store level (eg S001), or National level (eg SNAT), or no price at all.

**Required View Output:**

```
Store | Product | MAC Price | Sell Price
S001 |  123 |    15.00 |     25.00 
S001 |  456 |    17.50 |     25.00 
S002 |  123 |    16.00 |     26.00 
S002 |  456 |    17.50 |     40.00  (no Store specifc, therefore SNAT)
S002 |  789 |    20.00 |      0.00  (no Store specifc or SNAT)
```

My current code looks like below... I just don't know where/how to add the rules for "if no store specific price, use SNAT, else 0.00"...

```
create view SCH.Z_MAC_PRICE as
    select SCH.table1.store, SCH.table1.product, SCH.table1.mac,
           SCH.table2.sell
    from SCH.table1 left outer join
         SCH.table2
         on SCH.table1.store = SCH.table2.store and
            SCH.table1.product = SCH.table2.product
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd join table1 with table1 **twice**, once for the store level and once again for the national level, and display the national level only if the store level doesn't exist:

```
CREATE VIEW z_mac_price AS
SELECT      t1.store,
            t1.product,
            t1.mac_price,
            COALESCE(t2store.sell_price, t2nat.sell_pirce, 0.00)
FROM        table1 t1
LEFT JOIN   table2 t2store ON t2store.product = t1.product AND 
                              t2store.store = t1.store
LEFT JOIN   table2 t2nat ON t2nat.product = t1.product AND 
                            t2nat.store = 'SNAT'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want multiple `left join`s:

```
create view SCH.Z_MAC_PRICE as
    select t1.store, t1.product, t1.mac,
           coalesce(t2s.sell, t2n.sell, 0) as sell
    from SCH.table1 t1 left outer join
         SCH.table2 t2s
         on t2s.store = t1.store and
            t2s.product = t1.product left outer join
         SCH.table2 t2n
         on t2s.store = 'SNAT' and
            t2s.product = t1.product
```